# SwiftUI: For loop that appends to array is not functioning in Mutating function

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, swiftui, append

I have a for loop in a SwiftUI view that looks like this

```
for books in myHouse{
     newArray.append(books)
}
```

Loop works perfectly in my Swift project but in SwiftUI in my `struct ContentView: View` it says `Expected declaration`

So I put it in a func and receive these errors

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
```

So now I put it in a mutating function and it builds but the newArray remains empty.  Even when I try to use `@State` in a myriad of scenarios they all result to errors.

I have been heavily seeking documentation online and have sifted through articles but I have yet to found the solution to my issue.  What am I missing here with these errors?  How do you append to an array in a loop with SwiftUI?

Comment: You can’t use mutating functions in SwiftUI views. The most straightforward solution is using ‘@State’, which you said gave you errors, but you didn’t say what they are. My suggestion is to include the code you’ve tried for @State and you will probably get suggestions about what is going wrong.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you can't really do imperative code (like the loop you describe) inside the view hierarchy itself, but you can do it, for example, within `onAppear` or a `Button` action. Again, include your actual code and more helpful solutions can be given.